# Will a static string declaration containing calls to Regex.Replace() and/or String.Format() get optimized at compile time?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, declaration, static-members, compiler-optimization

According to the article ["How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) string literals and string constants will be concatentated into a single string at compile time. It further states that string variables can only be concatenated at run time.

I have string literals and enum value constants only, but I do have a slightly more complex scenario where these are combined with two static method calls. For readability and convenience purposes I declare a static string containing SQL as per the below example:

```
private enum StatGroup
{
    Test,
    ...
}

private static string TestSql =
        Regex.Replace(
            String.Format(
                @"INSERT INTO StatCounts (StatGroup, LinkStatus, LinkCount)
                    SELECT   '{0}', LinkStatus, COUNT(*)
                    FROM     LinkInfo
                    GROUP BY LinkStatus",
                StatGroup.Test),
            @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline),
```

I use String.Format(), so that I can utilize the enum for inserting valid value values into the `StatGroup` table column. I use Regex to remove the unnecessary whitespace in the SQL script. The whitespace is not required at run time, but serves well for readability of the code.

Is the compiler smart enough to optimize the above at compile time?

Comment: Considering that it only runs once in this case, it's hardly worth it.

Comment: True :) - But, if something could be optimized at compile time, why leave it to be executed at run time?

Comment: Do *you* want to be the one who has to make an exhaustive list of all functions that are safe to be optimized at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those are run-time function calls.  String concats of literals are easy for the compiler to join at compile time, but RegEx and string.Format are more complex and are run-time only.  String concat of literals is the special case.

Comment: That's a shame. Visual Studio is capable of executing extremely complex code when working with Windows forms at design time. You would think it would be capable of executing functions such as String.Format and Regex.Replace on literals and constants at compile time.

Comment: @Elan: It's capable of executing functions, it just doesn't know whether it's safe.  The analysis to check for side effects can get extremely complicated, it's easier to just make a list of functions like string.Concat which are known to be free of side effects.

Comment: You have to keep in mind what you are requesting is quite complex.  It happens to be a somewhat simple case in this case because it is strings we're talking about which are immutable.  But the compiler would have to be smart enough to analyze any function call you made to determine if they were time dependent, etc.  All in all, as @Gabe said, it's not worth it, you pay the cost once at startup and it is a very, very, very small cost.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the .NET optimizer is part of the JIT, it takes place at runtime.  So there's no benefit to optimizing code that will only run once (some Java VMs actually interpret code that will only run once to avoid the cost of compiling it).